# MPI collective operations implementation

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Are the MPI collective operations built on top of point-to-point operations ? Is the implementation of point-to-point operations improving ?

Answer (score 1):

This is implementation and interconnect dependent.

A simple implementation is likely based on point to point operations.

That being said, intra node collectives can use the shared memory and hence might not require any point to point operations.
Also, some hardware can be used to offload collective operations, and might be accessed via the higher level [Portals4](http://www.cs.sandia.gov/Portals/portals4.html) library.